# Why the following error occurs in the terminal while using linux commands?

Tags: command-line, process, limit

---

The following error occurs while using the below commands.Guide me to overcome this issue.

```
rpasa-vd1-363: cd /home/rpasa/DDEMO
No more processes.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hit our **per-user process limit** and you will have to talk to your system administrator to find out how many process you have running under your user account or you can try and run the `ps` command to see what processes you are running.

Comment: 'cd' is a shell command so shouldn't spawn a new process IIUC. Why does it seem to trigger this error?